# inserting into sorted list recursively

Tags: java, sorting, binary-search

How would you insert into a sorted array assuming the integers has been sorted into ascending order. I was told to use binary search, but that would only return the position of the element.

A example in pseudo-code would be grate.

Comment: is it homework then add homework tag?

Answer (score 2):

1. use a binary search (if this is a linked list, could be quite expensive iterating) to find the location where the new items belongs
2. if the value is the same - do nothing
3. If the value is different, need to insert here, which means moving everything back from this position to the end by one (if this is a linked list, simply means inserting a new node at this point, don't have to do all the shifting)
4. insert the new item at the index.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using static array e.g. no linked list

Following is a way to do with string array you can customize as per your requirement

// Create anarray with an ordered list of items
String[] sortedArray = new String[]{"ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"};

```
// Search for a non-existent item and then insert it
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedArray, "cow");
if (index < 0) {
    // Compute the insert index
    int insertIndex = -index-1;

    // Insert the new item into sortedArray. The example here creates
    // a new larger array to hold the new item.
    String[] newSortedArray = new String[sortedArray.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(sortedArray, 0, newSortedArray, 0, insertIndex);
    System.arraycopy(sortedArray, insertIndex,
                     newSortedArray, insertIndex+1,
                     sortedArray.length-insertIndex);
    newSortedArray[insertIndex] = "cow";
    sortedArray = newSortedArray;
}
```

refer http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_InsertInArray.html